# How to make my extended range floating point multiply more efficient?

Tags: c#, performance, floating-point

I am doing a calculation which frequently involves values like 3.47493E+17298. This is way beyond what a double can handle, and I don't need extra precision, just extra range of exponents, so I created my own little struct in C#.

My struct uses a long for significand and sign, and an int for exponent, so I effectively have:

1 sign bit
32 exponent bits (regular 2's complement exponent)
63 significand bits

I am curious what steps could be made to make my multiplication routine more efficient. I am running an enormous number of multiplications of these extended range values, and it is pretty fast, but I was looking for hints as to making it faster.

My multiplication routine:

```
    public static BigFloat Multiply(BigFloat left, BigFloat right)
    {
        long shsign1;
        long shsign2;

        if (left.significand == 0)
        {
            return bigZero;
        }

        if (right.significand == 0)
        {
            return bigZero;
        }

        shsign1 = left.significand;
        shsign2 = right.significand;

        // scaling down significand to prevent overflow multiply

        // s1 and s2 indicate how much the left and right 
        // significands need shifting.
        // The multLimit is a long constant indicating the
        // max value I want either significand to be
        int s1 = qshift(shsign1, multLimit);
        int s2 = qshift(shsign2, multLimit);

        shsign1 >>= s1;
        shsign2 >>= s2;

        BigFloat r;

        r.significand = shsign1 * shsign2;
        r.exponent = left.exponent + right.exponent + s1 + s2;

        return r;
    }
```

And the qshift:

It just finds out how much to shift the val to make it smaller in absolute value than the limit.

```
    public static int qshift(long val, long limit)
    {
        long q = val;
        long c = limit;
        long nc = -limit;

        int counter = 0;

        while (q > c || q < nc)
        {
            q >>= 1;
            counter++;
        }

        return counter;
    }
```

Comment: what are you computing that requires "values like 3.47493E+17298"?

Comment: Rather than creating your own, why not use an existing library such as http://sine.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Mitch: "I can name that tune in 1e17298 notes...". Another improvement would be loop unrolling in `qshift`.

Comment: I am computing the values of a sequence that grows almost as fast as a factorial. Its a pretty strange sequence, so it took about 3000 values to real start to understand when the sequence is positive and when negative, and to get a good estimate of its growth.

The more performance improvements I can get the more values I can calculate quickly. I have already drastically improved the main algorithm from n^3 to n^2

Comment: Just porting my current algorithm to C++ was a major improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a completely different idea...

Use the hardware's floating-point machinery, but augment it with your own integer exponents.  Put another way, make `BigFloat.significand` be a floating-point number instead of an integer.

Then you can use `ldexp` and `frexp` to keep the actual exponent on the float equal to zero.  These should be single machine instructions.

So BigFloat multiply becomes:

- `r.significand = left.significand * right.significand`
- `r.exponent = left.exponent + right.exponent`
- `tmp =` (actual exponent of r.significand from frexp)
- `r.exponent += tmp`
- (use ldexp to subtract `tmp` from actual exponent of `r.significand`)

Unfortunately,the last two steps require `frexp` and `ldexp`, which searches suggest are not available in C#.  So you might have to write this bit in C.

...

Or, actually...

Use floating-point numbers for the significands, but just keep them normalized between 1 and 2.  So again, use floats for the significands, and multiply like this:

```
r.significand = left.significand * right.significand;
r.exponent = left.exponent + right.exponent;
if (r.significand >= 2) {
    r.significand /= 2;
    r.exponent += 1;
}
assert (r.significand >= 1 && r.significand < 2);  // for debugging...
```

This should work as long as you maintain the invariant mentioned in the assert().  (Because if x is between 1 and 2 and y is between 1 and 2 then x*y is between 1 and 4, so the normalization step is just has to check for when the significand product is between 2 and 4.)

You will also need to normalize the results of additions etc., but I suspect you are already doing that.

Although you will need to special-case zero after all :-).

[edit, to flesh out the `frexp` version]

```
BigFloat BigFloat::normalize(BigFloat b)
{
    double temp = b.significand;
    double tempexp = b.exponent;
    double temp2, tempexp2;
    temp2 = frexp(temp, &tempexp2);
    // Need to test temp2 for infinity and NaN here
    tempexp += tempexp2;
    if (tempexp < MIN_EXP)
        // underflow!
    if (tempexp > MAX_EXP)
        // overflow!
    BigFloat r;
    r.exponent = tempexp;
    r.significand = temp2;
}
```

In other words, I would suggest factoring this out as a "normalize" routine, since presumably you want to use it following additions, subtractions, multiplications, and divisions.

And then there are all the corner cases to worry about...

You probably want to handle underflow by returning zero.  Overflow depends on your tastes; should either be an error or +-infinity.  Finally, if the result of frexp() is infinity or NaN, the value of `tempexp2` is undefined, so you might want to check those cases, too.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I am thinking of trying a C implementation anyway, so I will go for your first idea. Using more of the floating point hardware sounds like a good idea.

Comment: BigFloat BigFloat::Multiply(BigFloat left, BigFloat right)
{
 double temp = left.significand * right.significand;
 double tempexp = left.exponent + right.exponent;

 double temp2;
 double tempexp2;

 temp2 = frexp(temp, &tempexp2);

 tempexp += tempexp2;

 BigFloat r;
 r.exponent = tempexp;
 r.significand = temp2;
}

Comment: The c++ version of my application is actually slower, and I think it is because the BigFloat uses floats instead of integer types, and in both cases, you have to scale your results. I will test this by implementing the integer version of BigFloat in C++. Currently the C# version has calculated the 1000th value of the sequence by the time the C++ version on the 750th value.

Comment: The integer algorithm, rewritten in C++ was faster than anything else. So I don't think using floats worked out in this case. Maybe it would work for a different use case than mine. But all I am doing with my BigFloat is addition and multiplication (and a ToStr).

Comment: Oh well.  Was worth a shot :-)

Comment: Thanks for the idea at least. Going to C++ was a learning experience and did speed things up. It took some adjusting to get used to not having all the tools of C#.

Answer (score 1):

I am not much of a C# programmer, but here are some general ideas.

First, are there any profiling tools for C#?  If so, start with those...

The time is very likely being spent in your qshift() function; in particular, the loop.  Mispredicted branches are nasty.

I would rewrite it as:

```
long q = abs(val);
int x = q/nc;
(find next power of 2 bigger than x)
```

For that last step, see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525122/c-math-question-smallest-power-of-2-bigger-than-x).

Then instead of shifting by qshift, just divide by this power of 2.  (Does C# have "find first set" (aka. ffs)?  If so, you can use it to get the shift count from the power of 2; it should be one instruction.)

Definitely inline this sequence if the compiler will not do it for you.

Also, I would ditch the special cases for zero, unless you are multiplying by zero a *lot*.  Linear code good; conditionals bad.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. I will look into that.

Comment: Also I do have a profiling tool, and it only shows about 1/5th the time of Multiply being spent in qshift. Dividing q by nc and then finding the power of 2 of the quotient actually is slower than just shifting q until it is less in magnitude, at least that was what my profiler showed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure there won't be an overflow, you can use an **[unchecked block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx)**.

That will remove the overflow checks, and give you a bit more performance.

Comment: I know there will be overflows because I am using as many bits of the signficand as I can to keep precision. So after the first couple terms of my sequence, most of the values of the significand will be near max or min int.